# Why are constructors returned by ReflectionFactor.newConstructorForSerialization() called "munged"?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, instantiation

In Java, one can create instances of a class without actually calling a declared constructor by retrieving one via sun.reflect.ReflectionFactor.newConstructorForSerialization().

As far as I know, this special constructor is called "munged". Where does this term come from? I could not find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Why do you think it is called "munged"? I never heard this, do you got a link by the hand?

Comment: http://svn.xstream.codehaus.org/browse/xstream/trunk/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/Sun14ReflectionProvider.java?r=HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's used as in the following sense, because you are somehow bypassing/faking the normal object creation cycle, by skipping the constructor:

> (computing) modify or fake an email
>   (or other internet) address so it
>   cannot be automatically harvested,
>   esp. to avoid spam bots
>
> (computing) change a file; make
>   irrevocable changes, destroy,
>   obfuscate

Both definitions are from Princeton's WordNet.

Answer (score 0):

From the wiktionary:

> [To transform data in an undefined or
>   unexplained manner.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/munge)

The constructor for deserialisation does not [necessarily] call the super class constructor and is not part of the original class. From a JVM spec perspective, it is illegal - a munged version of a legal constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, classes from the package sun.* should not be used directly as they may not be available on other JDK implementations (so this "constructor" may be undefined with another JDK).

Comment: You could use objenesis: http://code.google.com/p/objenesis/

There are situations where you have to bypass constructors:

 *  Serialization, Remoting and Persistence  - Objects need to be instantiated and restored to a specific state, without invoking code.
 * Proxies, AOP Libraries and Mock Objects - Classes can be subclassed without needing to worry about the super() constructor.
 * Container Frameworks - Objects can be dynamically instantatiated in non-standard ways.

(Taken from the website above.)