# Deserialize a final list attribute

Tags: java, xstream

Suppose we have a class Test like:

```
public class Test {
    private final String name;
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void add(String s) {
        list.add(s);
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(" - " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Without XSteam the invariant

```
this.list != null
```

holds every time.

But if we look in the 4th test in

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("test", Test.class);

    // Serialize
    final Test test1 = new Test("XYZ");
    test1.add("One");
    test1.add("Two");

    //@formatter:off
    /* name: XYZ
     *  - One
     *  - Two
     */
    //@formatter:on
    test1.print();

    //@formatter:off
    /* <test>
     *   <name>XYZ</name>
     *   <list>
     *     <string>One</string>
     *     <string>Two</string>
     *   </list>
     * </test>
     */
    //@formatter:on
    System.out.println(xstream.toXML(test1));

    // Deserialize with one list entry
    final String xmlTest2 = "<test><name>XYZ</name><list><string>One</string></list></test>";
    final Test test2 = (Test) xstream.fromXML(xmlTest2);
    //@formatter:off
    /* <test>
     *   <name>XYZ</name>
     *   <list>
     *     <string>One</string>
     *   </list>
     * </test>
     */
    //@formatter:on
    test2.print();

    // Deserialize with empty list
    final String xmlTest3 = "<test><name>XYZ</name><list /></test>";
    final Test test3 = (Test) xstream.fromXML(xmlTest3);
    //@formatter:off
    /* name: XYZ
     */
    //@formatter:on
    test3.print();

    // Deserialize without list-tag
    final String xmlTest4 = "<test><name>XYZ</name></test>";
    final Test test4 = (Test) xstream.fromXML(xmlTest4);
    //@formatter:off
    /* name: XYZ
     * Exception in thead ... NullPointerException
     */
    //@formatter:on
    test4.print();
}
```

we see a NullPointerException, because `list` was not initialized.

I'd like to have the `list`-element in the XML optional similiar to test4. What can I do? Because there are many classes in my datamodel similiar to `Test`, I don't want to write a `Converter` for every class. But suppose I would write a `Converter`, how can I set the final attribute `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XStream uses munged constructors (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426106/why-are-constructors-returned-by-reflectionfactor-newconstructorforserialization) in enhanced mode (default). You can change this behavior by initializing XStream in pure mode:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new PureJavaReflectionProvider());
```

Another option is to access variables using getters and implement lazy initialization.

```
public class Test {
private final String name;
private List<String> list;

public Test(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

void add(String s) {
    list.add(s);
}

List<String> getList() {
  if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  return list;
}

void print() {
    System.out.println("name: " + name);
    for (String s : getList()) {
        System.out.println(" - " + s);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your first suggestion work's well. I use the `PureJavaReflectionProvider`. Additional I must write a private constructor, that initializes fields with `null` that are not initialized by the declaration, in this case `name`. Although `name` is initialized with `null`, XStream is able to set it to `"XYZ"`. Becouse of the constructor is private, this is an elegant way to let the fields final.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following solution using XStream [Annotations and a custom Converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html).

The custom converter is the following class:

```
 public class ListableConverter implements Converter {

    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
            MarshallingContext context) {
        Listable listable = (Listable) source;
        writer.setValue(String.valueOf(... your marshalling logic here ...));
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
            UnmarshallingContext context) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        // your unmarshalling logic here
        return list;
    }

    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type instanceof Listable;
    }
}
```

This is the modified Test class with Annotations:

```
public class Test implements Listable{
    private final String name;

    @XStreamConverter(ListableConverter.class)
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public Test(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void add(String s) {
        list.add(s);
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        for (String s : list) {
            System.out.println(" - " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the interface used to make the converter good for any class in your model implementing the interface:

```
public interface Listable<String> {

    public List<String> getList();

}
```

So, for example, another class in your model may looks like:

```
    public class Foo implements Listable{

        @XStreamConverter(ListableConverter.class)
        private final List<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<>();

        ... omissis ...

        public List<String> getList() {
          return anotherList;
        }

   }
```

Comment: Thank you! I get confused when I try this solution. You've annotated the field `list` with `@XStreamConverter(ListableConverter.class)`. `ListableConverter` can't convert `ArrayList` but only `Listable`s. Either I have to write 1) the `Converter` for the hole class or 2) for `List`s. With 1) I have to write for each class an own `Converter`; with 2), `unmarshal` would never called, becouse there is no `<list>`-element in the XML.